# Unix_Timestamp from database

Tags: php, mysql

On my website I have made a automatic invoice system. It will generate a invoice for a certain user from a certain month. You can select the user, month and year and then click generate.

But, In my MYSQL Database, I've stored the products the user ordered on date with a Unix Timestamp. now I want to load all the products from a certain month by checking if the Unix Timestamp matches. But it won't work.

My code:

```
require "connect.php";
$create_by=$_GET['user'];
$jaar=$_GET['jaar'];
$maand=$_GET['maand'];
$number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $maand, $jaar);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM `mrbs_entry`
WHERE start_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(".$jaar."-".$maand."-01)
AND start_time <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(".$jaar."-".$maand."-".$number.")
AND create_by = '".$create_by".' 
ORDER BY `start_time`, `room_id`");
```

The date is given through the link, like user, maand, jaar.

maand is the month, and jaar is the year.

Comment: Is `start_time` a UNIX timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't quote your date values within the query, so effectively you're building

```
... WHERE start_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2016-01-15)
```

That's not a date value, it's a double mathematical subtraction, and you're really executing `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2000)`, which is way back in 1970.

```
WHERE start_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('".$jaar."-".$maand."-01')
                                   ^-----------------------^
```

Note the indicated quotes. And also note that you're wide open for [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: What do you mean with sql injection attacks

Comment: I love that xkcd-strip!